# How can I get new results from randint while in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

My code thus far:

```
from random import randint

Dice1 = randint(1,6)
Dice2 = randint(1,6)
Dice3 = randint(1,6)

DiceRoll2 = Dice1 + Dice2
DiceRoll3 = Dice1 + Dice2 + Dice3

class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value, desc):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.desc = desc

sword = Item("Sword", 2, "A regular sword.")

class Monster(object):
    def __init__(self, name, health, attack):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.attack = attack

monster = Monster("Monster", 50, DiceRoll2)

Damage = DiceRoll3 + sword.value
NewHealth = monster.health - Damage

print("You see a monster!")

while True:
    action = input("? ").lower().split()

    if action[0] == "attack":
        print("You swing your", sword.name, "for", Damage, "damage!")
        print("The", monster.name, "is now at", NewHealth, "HP!")

    elif action[0] == "exit":
        break
```

The intension is that with every time you enter "attack" you get a random result of DiceRoll3 (three random numbers from 1 to 6, that three times), add the value of the sword and substract that from the monster's starting health. This goes well until I enter "attack" a second time, which results in the same damage and the same reduced health being printed instead of using a new value. How can I properly do this?

Comment: You'll need to make the call to `randint()` inside your loop, or write a function to do it and call it in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Put your dice-rolling into a separate function and calculate `Damage` and `NewHealth` inside your loop. (Also, update your Monster's health. :))

```
from random import randint

def dice_roll(times):
  sum = 0
  for i in range(times):
    sum += randint(1, 6)
  return sum

class Item(object):
  def __init__(self, name, value, desc):
    self.name = name
    self.value = value
    self.desc = desc

sword = Item("Sword", 2, "A regular sword.")

class Monster(object):
  def __init__(self, name, health, attack):
    self.name = name
    self.health = health
    self.attack = attack

monster = Monster("Monster", 50, dice_roll(2))

print("You see a monster!")

while True:
  action = input("? ").lower().split()

  if action[0] == "attack":
    Damage = dice_roll(3) + sword.value
    NewHealth = max(0, monster.health - Damage)   #prevent a negative health value
    monster.health = NewHealth                    #save the new health value
    print("You swing your", sword.name, "for", Damage, "damage!")
    print("The", monster.name, "is now at", NewHealth, "HP!")

  elif action[0] == "exit":
    break

  if monster.health < 1:
    print("You win!")
    break
```

Comment: This works very well, but I'm trying to figure out how to use this for different monsters. If I were to define for example a Minotaur and a Goblin as well, how can I load them? I'm reading from a dictionary called `rooms[currentRoom]["monster"]`, with `currentRoom` being the number of a sub-dictionary that contains a number of things on that room, with `"monster"` containing the name of the monster which is in that room. The properties of the monster however will be below the Monster class.

Comment: I'd create a class `Room` that holds a reference to a `Monster` object (or a list of possible objects). You can save these objects like other variables, i.e. `rooms[currentRoom]["monster"] = Monster("Goblin", 42, 3)`.

Comment: Yep, that worked. Just a simple `class Monster(object):` with the important information about the monster. I had to number them by hand though so they match up with the particular room so I get `rooms[1]["monster"]` instead of with `currentRoom` in place of the number, but given that the line in question already contains information on the monster that's not much of a hassle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the call to randint everytime. Below is one way to do it

```
def Dice1(): return  randint(1,6)
def Dice2(): return  randint(1,6)
def Dice3(): return  randint(1,6)
```

This isn't great though because of all the repeated code. Here is a better way

```
class Dice(object):
    def roll_dice(self):
        return randint(1,6)

Dice1 = Dice()
Dice2 = Dice()
Dice3 = Dice()
```

Now in your code where ever you call `Dice1`, `Dice2` or `Dice3`; instead call `Dice1.roll_dice()`, `Dice2.roll_dice()`, `Dice3.roll_dice()`. This abstract away the dice implementation and you are free to change it later without having to change your code.

If you need have dice with different number of faces, you only need to change your dice class

```
class Dice(object):
    def __init__ (self, num_faces=6):
        self.faces = num_faces

    def roll_dice(self):
        return randint(1,self.faces)

Dice1 = Dice() # 6 faced die
Dice2 = Dice(20) # 20 faced die
```

Comment: How exactly can I in that second bit of code get the result of several dice rolls? I've tried adding print(Dice2.roll_dice()) but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It's exactly what you posted in that second block copied 1:1 with identical indentation, but with from random import randint on line 1 (your code starts on line 3), with on line 11 print(Dice2.roll_dice()).

Comment: if you are using python3 change `class Dice(object):` to `class Dice:`

Comment: No wait I get it, I just have to use things like `print(Dice1.roll_dice() + Dice2.roll_dice())` to get multiple rolls. Or is this an unwieldy way of doing things?

Comment: re unweildy: it depends on the amount of code you are writing. If you will need to use dice in multiple places, or you will use the script for a long time, then classes make sense. If you are creating a throwaway script, then just use randint directly

Comment: If you use this `Dice` class, you won't need more than one object. But a method for adding up multiple rolls would be nice.